# trouble while running for code in Product Market introduction

Tags: netlogo

I 'm new here, and I am encountering a problem. I have taken an already existing code for 2 new products entering the market and I am trying to modify it to support 3 products. I have added all the extra variables and conditions needed but it shows an error on plotting. Could it be the excel or...? I could use some help on this...If any extra info is needed, I 'd be happy to provide you! Thanks for your time in advance!

the error is:
http://prntscr.com/9gy84l

Comment: It appears that you added variables and conditions, but did not add an additional plot pen to the plot.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you added variables and conditions, but did not add an additional plot pen to the plot. You can add the pen by editing the plot itself.